# Zend Framework 2 not displaying errors when instantiating classes which don't exist

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm having problems debugging my code whilst trying to learn Zend Framework 2.

Intially I have been trying to implement Zend\Captcha\ReCaptcha and kept receiving black pages. However I have worked it back to the fact that when I attempt to instantiate an object from a non-existent class I do not get any errors. Just a blank page.

E.g:

```
public function indexAction()
{


   new Zend\Captcha\ReCaptcha();
   //or
   new Some_Class_Which_Doesnt_Exist();
}
```

The result is a blank page. If I comment the instantiations out I get my standard layout page.

My PHP error reporting is set as:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

I'm guessing this is something to do with Zend Framework. Can I force it to display errors to help me with debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `display_errors` option in php.ini, maybe it is set to `0`.